# AngularJS with ASP.NET Web API and Azure AD Single SignOn using msal

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have an asp.net web api and angularjs(1.4.x) app and planning to use Azure AD for authentication and single sign on feature. Most of the examples are using ADAL, which is deprecated as per Microsoft. Can anyone share some examples of what changes need to be done in Web api and AngularJS app?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The web application uses ASP.NET Web API and Angular JS technology and is hosted on IIS (On Premise) using Windows authentication. As the application is being migrated to Azure, there is a necessity to switch to Azure AD authentication. I have already added Azure AD Authentication to Web API and need to configure AngularJS SPA with Azure AD where, I need to add MSAL to Angular JS application. Most of the examples, I have are using ADAL.js I am looking for some examples with MSAL using AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

Migrate ADAL.js to MSAL.js for Azure AD Authentication for AngularJS+ASP.NET Core application.

You could try @azure/msal-angularjs for AngularJS SPA

When migrating ADAL.js to MSAL.js, you need to use @azure/msal-angular that is based on Microsoft identity platform v2.0.

Below is the example using MSAL Angular and call a .NET Core web API.

Example : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api

Reference Guide Based on SO Thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-compare-msal-js-and-adal-js

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-migration